# How do I execute a function on ClassB when something changes in ClassA?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I have a game written with SwiftUI with two classes, a Game class to manage the game, and a ScoreStore class that manages an array of high scores. Currently the score of a game is stored (via a function on ScoreStore) when the user presses a button (displayed in the ContentView struct) to start a new game. I want to have the score saved when a game reaches a certain state (considered here to be a certain score).

Both Game and ScoreStore are ObservableObjects and have @Published properties available to ContentView as @EnvironmentObjects. Within Game, score is not @Published because it is a computed property.

```
class Game: ObservableObject, Codable {
    
    var deck: [Card] = []
    
    @Published var piles: [[Card]] = [[],[],[],[]] 

    var score: Int {
        let fullDeckCount = 52
        var cardsOnThePiles = 0
        for pile in piles {
            cardsOnThePiles += pile.count
        }
        return fullDeckCount - deck.count - cardsOnThePiles
    }
```

```
class ScoresStore: Codable, ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    
    @Published var highScores: [Score] = []
    
    func addScore(newScore: Int, date: Date = Date()) {
        // Do things to add the score to the array
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var game: Game
    @EnvironmentObject var scores: ScoresStore

func saveScore() {
        scores.addScore(newScore: game.score)
    }
    
var body: some View {
    Button(action: { saveScore }) {
        Text("New Game?")
    }
}
```

I've looked at questions whose answers reference binding via a @State property but in this case the property I'm "observing" is in Game (not ContentView).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `PassThroughSubject` to allow your views to be triggered to do something when the `@Published` values change. Then, on your view, you use an `.onReceive` to trigger your functions.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var game: Game
    @EnvironmentObject var scores: ScoresStore
    
    func saveScore() {
        scores.addScore(newScore: game.score)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { saveScore }) {
            Text("New Game?")
        }
        .onReceive(game.objectDidChange, perform: { _ in
            //Do something here
        })
        .onReceive(scores.objectDidChange, perform: { _ in
            //Do something here
        })
    }
}

final class Game: NSObject, ObservableObject, Codable {
    
    let objectDidChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    
    var deck: [Card] = []
    
    @Published var piles: [[Card]] = [[],[],[],[]] {
        didSet {
            self.objectDidChange.send()
        }
    }
    
    var score: Int {...}
}

final class ScoresStore: NSObject, Codable, ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    
    let objectDidChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    
    @Published var highScores: [Score] = [] {
        didSet {
            self.objectDidChange.send()
        }
    }
    
    func addScore(newScore: Int, date: Date = Date()) {
        // Do things to add the score to the array
    }
}
```

Every time `Game.piles` or `ScoreStore.highScores` updates, you will get a notice to the `.onReceive` in your view, so you can deal with it. I suspect you will want to keep track of the game score this way as well, and trigger on that change. You can then test for whatever you want and implement whatever action you desire. You will also note that I did this on a `didSet`. You will also see this as an `objectWillSet` placed into a `willSet` on the variable. Both work, but the `willSet` sends a trigger before the actual update, whereas `didSet` sends it after. It may not make a difference, but I have had this as an issue in the past. Lastly, I imported `Combine` at the top, but I did these in one file. Wherever you define the `passThroughSubject` you will need to import `Combine`. The view does not actually need to import it. Good luck.